# Create numbers of new columns with new names in R

Tags: r

So I have a `data.frame` called "test" that look like this:

```
   Date        Amount
1  01/01/2019  200.0000
2  02/01/2019  200.0000
3  03/01/2019  100.0000
4  04/01/2019  300.0000
5  05/01/2019  500.0000
6  06/01/2019  600.0000
7  07/01/2019  700.0000
8  08/01/2019  800.0000
```

I'm trying to create new about 5 new columns using dplyr `mutate()` function. Here is my code for that:

```
numoflag <- c(1:5)
lapply(numoflag, function(x){
  newcolname <-paste0("Amountlag",x)
  test <- test %>% mutate(newcolname = lag(Amount,x))
})
```

What I intended is `data.frame` "test" will be populated with new 5 columns with names like "Amountlag1", "Amountlag2", ... However, I got something like this 5 times in the console:

```
   Date        Amount     newcolname
1  01/01/2019  200.0000         NA
2  02/01/2019  200.0000   200.0000
3  03/01/2019  100.0000   200.0000
4  04/01/2019  300.0000   100.0000
5  05/01/2019  500.0000   300.0000
6  06/01/2019  600.0000   500.0000
7  07/01/2019  700.0000   600.0000
8  08/01/2019  800.0000   700.0000
```

So instead of using the object `newcolname`'s value, its name is being use. And also my function only printout the result without changing anything in the `data.frame` "test". I can't figure out where did I mess it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to do with what base R already has:

```
test[paste0('newColumn', 1:5)] <- 
    lapply(1:5, function(x) dplyr::lag(test$Amount, x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` (which is same as `lapply`) with `transmute` to make new columns

```
library(dplyr)

bind_cols(df, purrr::map(1:5, 
           ~ df %>% transmute(!!paste0("Amountlag", .x) := lag(Amount, .x))))


#        Date Amount Amountlag1 Amountlag2 Amountlag3 Amountlag4 Amountlag5
#1 01/01/2019    200         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#2 02/01/2019    200        200         NA         NA         NA         NA
#3 03/01/2019    100        200        200         NA         NA         NA
#4 04/01/2019    300        100        200        200         NA         NA
#5 05/01/2019    500        300        100        200        200         NA
#6 06/01/2019    600        500        300        100        200        200
#7 07/01/2019    700        600        500        300        100        200
#8 08/01/2019    800        700        600        500        300        100
```